# Limitations with Wine

Tags: linux, wine, emulator

Are there any limitations on what Wine/Windows Emulators can do? I mean this primarily from a point of view of Web Browsers communicating with applications that use them. (E.g.: Firefox and the in-built mail tool, as an example)

---

#### Edit:

What I am needing to find out, is if Wine is compatible with a normal windows (written in .NET) application, and if specifically needed, ClickOnce technology.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question. Do you mean starting a program in WINE, which then calls the native Firefox?

Comment: @Bobby - Clarified a bit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know about ClickOnce, but DotNet up to 3.0 is [working flawlessly](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=2586) in WINE.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I just asked another question which you may be able to answer if you don't mind. http://superuser.com/questions/113750/wine-and-kernel-access

Answer (score 1):

There are no hard limitations per se with Wine as far as I can tell. The problems you run into are from parts of the wine libraries, which aren't implemented yet, or aren't quite perfect.

Windows Emulators usually are quite separated from the underlying system if that's what you are concerned with, so may not work well for you.

Your question isn't very clear, so I wasn't sure which way to elaborate more. Care to expand it? :)

Comment: @Ivan - Thanks thus far, I have clarified further.